# Recovering deleted files on an encrypted drive

Tags: fedora, data-recovery, disk-encryption

My drive is encrypted. I am running Fedora.  I also have a Win 10 boot (not encrypted), if that's relevant)

I accidentally ran `rm -Rf *` in the wrong folder - one in which I had a dozen or so small text files.

Is there any way to recover these files?

Comment: Consider restoring from backup. That's usually easier.

Answer (score 0):

The first major rule of recovering deleted files: stop writing to the affected partition(s)!

If the files are sufficiently small, you can simply run any hex editor on `/dev/mappper/luks*` or `/dev/dm-?` and find them using a pattern. Alternatively you can dump the entire partition to your Windows partition, e.g.

```
cat /dev/dm-? > /mnt/Windows/linux-decrypted.img
```

And then use e.g. R-Studio Undelete to search for and recover deleted files. In my experience it's the best file recovery utility.